# How do I disable debug checks in yaws?

Tags: erlang, yaws

When i start yaws (`yaws -i --conf config/yaws.conf`) i get this line in the output:

Running with debug checks turned on (slower server)

It depends on the "-i" option? Or where did i turned on debug checks? No mention of debug in the config file...

thx
edoardo

Answer (score 3):

In recent versions of yaws (1.85 and later) you can simply pass the --nodebug option on the command line:

```
yaws -i --nodebug
```

Answer (score 1):

This will be because your `flags` setting in the global config has the debug bit (2) set. If GC_DEBUG is set in the global configuration this feature will be enabled.

These are the flags:

```
-define(GC_TTY_TRACE,                        1).
-define(GC_DEBUG,                            2).
-define(GC_AUTH_LOG,                         4).
-define(GC_COPY_ERRLOG,                      8).
-define(GC_BACKWARDS_COMPAT_PARSE,          16).
-define(GC_LOG_RESOLVE_HOSTNAME,            32).
-define(GC_FAIL_ON_BIND_ERR,                64).
-define(GC_PICK_FIRST_VIRTHOST_ON_NOMATCH, 128).
-define(GC_USE_FDSRV,                      256).
-define(GC_USE_OLD_SSL,                    512).
```

I think that in the yaws.config file this is actually un-set by setting the debug = false flag in the global part.

Updated - the debug parameter is part of the env settings of the app in the yaws.app file, so adding something like

```
-yaws debug false
```

to the *real* command line should work

Comment: hi, Alan and thx for your reply.
When I saw it I said: "Obvious, why I've not tried..." but then I tried and got this reply from yaws: "Yaws: Bad conf: "Unexpected tokens \"debug\" at line 4". So what is true for the other flags seems not to apply to 'debug'.

thx again.

Comment: Sorry - have a look at your yaws.app file (if you're running yaws standalone) - it'll be in erlx.y.z/lib/yaws-a.b/ebin/yaws.app. The mysterious debug parameter is part of the env settings in that file, and as it is an application parameter you should also be able to control it on the command line.

Comment: ( I of course assumed it would map in the GC record but a little bit further down the code it was obvious it was coming from the environment and not the config...!)

Answer (score 0):

After using command: "sudo yaws -i --nodebug", my website become a bit faster.